# Using OneLogin to acces a ADFS IDP

Tags: php, saml, adfs, onelogin

I am trying to use the onelogin php toolkit for SAML to access a ADFS IDP on a different domain.  ADFS just displays a screen with the following

> Error details
>   Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-f980-0080000400cd
>   Error time: Thu, 24 Aug 2017 13:48:15 GMT
>   Cookie: enabled
>   User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063

I believe this to be an access control problem as when I compare what gets sent to the onelogin demo and ADFS the only difference is that the Cookie information is not sent.  Is this access control and what is the fix?

Comment: Get the adfs event log entry from this time. Else you are just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask the ADFS admin about the error related with that trace ID.

At php-saml try to not set any RequestAuthnContext value and verify that the NameIdFormat that you are using is supported by ADFS.

Is a configuration issue, ADFS and php-saml settings need to be aligned.

If you install firefox's SAMLTracer extension you will be able to record the AuthNRequest that you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a misconfiguration issue the saml:Issuer defineed in the SAML request was not exactly matched in ADFS (there was one upercase letter in the request but it was a lower case letter on the ADFS Identifiers tab)